# Change date format for AD expiry date

Tags: powershell

It outputs as 9/18/2021 8:07:39 PM and I wish to format this to DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss . How can I do that?

```
([datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed"))
```

output : 9/18/2021 8:07:39 PM

Here is my script :

```
..

..        if ($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" -ne 9223372036854775807) {
            # This is standard situation where users password is expiring as needed
            try {
                $DateExpiry = ([datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed"))
            } catch {
                $DateExpiry = $_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed"
            }
            try {
                $DaysToExpire = (New-TimeSpan -Start (Get-Date) -End ([datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed"))).Days
            } catch {
                $DaysToExpire = $null
            }

..

..
..
```

Answer (score 1):

`FromFileTime` [Returns a `datetime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.fromfiletime?view=net-5.0#returns) object. So you can call [`ToString` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=net-5.0#System_DateTime_ToString_System_String_) of this object with the format you need.

```
(Get-Date).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
```

This will print *08-09-2021 12:59:17*

Comment: thanks, I don't understand what you mean by "ToString method call". how can we use ToString method for $DateExpiry = ([datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed"))  ?  can you send me sample line?

Comment: @Arbelac `$DateExpiry` is now holds an instance of DatetimeObject. So you can just call `$DateExpiry.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss")` to convert it into the required format

Comment: Or you can combine everything into a single expression `([datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss")`

Comment: thanks how can I add AM and PM for `ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss")` ?

Comment: @Arbelac You can use `tt`, ie, `ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")`

Comment: ok lastly , how can we add as 24-hour format  instead of AM/PM format ?

Comment: @Arbelac You can use `HH` instead of `hh` to convert it into 24 hour format.`ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")`